# How can I loop with more than 1 variable at once in Common Lisp?

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

So, I can loop with one variable like this:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3 4 5) do (print i))
```

I can get 1 number and bind it to i.

But how can I bind to more than 1 variable at once, e.g. something like:

```
for i,j,k in '(1 2 3 4 5)
-> i = 1, j = 2, k = 3
```

I already tried searching around but only found `with` statement to define more variables, but it does not allow me to bind the variables directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the other answer.  If you simply wish to iterate with multiple variables then then you can do this by

```
(loop for x ...
      for y ...
      do ...)
```

This does sequential binding: when `y` is stepped, `x` has already been stepped.  Parallel binding happens with `and`:

```
(loop for x ...
      and y ...
      do ...)
```

If you want to destructure a single list, then you can use destructuring.  But the destructuring `loop` does is kind of horrible, and in particular it is not, of course, compatible with the destructuring done b `destructuring-bind` or (equivalently) macro lambda lists.  In particular as the other answer shows `(a b c)` *does* match `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`, or indeed `()`.

However the other answer is probably unsafe in general.  Consider this function:

```
(defun foo (l)
  (loop for (a b c) on l by #'cddr
        while c
        do (print (list a b c))))
```

Well now consider `(foo '(1 2 nil 3 4 5))`.

A better approach is this, which both avoids the worst horrors of `loop`'s destructuring, and gets the termination condition closer to right, as well as being, probably, slightly more efficient:

```
(defun foo (l)
  (loop for (a b c . tail) = l then tail
        do (print (list a b c))
        while tail))
```

Now

```
> (foo '(1 2 nil 3 4 5))

(1 2 nil) 
(3 4 5) 
nil
```

Comment: Very nice to see that loop macro can do pattern matching like that.

Comment: very nice! For the case that nil is an element of the list, you could do:

`(loop for (a b c . d) on '(1 2 nil 4 5) by #'cdr
  while (or c d)
  do (print (list a b c)))
`

Answer (score 0):

Following Eldinur answer that unfortunately forces you to change the `by #'cddr` each time you change the length of the variables list, you could do the following :

```
(defmacro for (vars in lst &body body)
  (assert (string= in "IN") nil "Malformed FOR. You must use IN instead of ~S." in)
  `(loop for ,vars on ,lst
         by #'(lambda (l) (nthcdr ,(length vars) l))
         do ,@body))
```

Then, you could do things like this :

```
CL-USER> (for (i j k) in '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
           (print (list i j k)))

(1 2 3) 
(4 5 6)
NIL
```

Note that you can use `nil` value inside the values list :

```
CL-USER> (for (i j k) in '(1 2 nil 4 5 6)
           (print (list i j k)))

(1 2 NIL) 
(4 5 6) 
NIL
```

And you can have different lengths between the variables list and the values list :

```
CL-USER> (for (i j k) in '(1 2 3 4 5)
           (print (list i j k)))

(1 2 3) 
(4 5 NIL) 
NIL
```

Comment: I don't claim that my answer is great because I don't use lisp often (I'm more of a C++ guy). I just  found a solution that works. So yes, your right that your solution is more responsive and better overall. :)